# BeautifulSoup children of ordered list <ol>, no results

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, webscarab

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse code from Craigslist. But when I'm using find_all command, I'm getting an empty list as output. If anyone could point out where I'm making a mistake or show me a better solution I would be grateful!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

url = "https://vancouver.craigslist.org/search/cta?query=tesla#search=1~gallery~0~0"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

sleep(4)

results = soup.find("div", class_="results")
print(results)

parent = results.find("ol")

# I can not accees <li> elements here
li_elements = parent.find_all("li", class_="cl-search-result cl-search-view-mode-gallery")
print(li_elements)

for li in li_elements:
 print("not empty")
 print(li.text)
```

Comment: Maybe you should move *`soup = BeautifulSoup...`* to **after** `sleep(4)`?

Answer (score 0):

As **Driftr95** mentioned, you need to wait until the contents get loaded on the page before getting the page source. This URL/website in particular is a bit slow in loading at the start.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

url = "https://vancouver.craigslist.org/search/cta?query=tesla#search=1~gallery~0~0"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

results = soup.find("div", class_="results")
parent = results.find("ol")
li_elements = parent.find_all("li", class_="cl-search-result cl-search-view-mode-gallery")

for li in li_elements:
    print(li.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a nice tool, but I hate using it for web scraping tasks, since it is so slow to load and often blocked by Cloudflare.

What I personally do in such situations is I try to find out the api call, that your browser makes to fetch the data.
Just use your browser [Developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLS8J.png), go to **Network->Fetch/XHR** and scan through all the request links that you'll find here.
What you end up with is a bunch of raw json data that is sooo nice to work with.

So, as an example, this would give you the 15k-ish line json file with 359 different  Teslas:

```
import requests, json

data = requests.get('https://sapi.craigslist.org/web/v8/postings/search/full?batch=16-0-360-0-0&cc=US&lang=en&query=tesla&searchPath=cta').json()

with open('craigs_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

What is even better, after you understand how the API call url`s are constructed, you can even make up the links by yourself. However, I must warn you.

**API's are not intended to be directly called by users! Don't try to request them too often, unless you want your IP to get banned by their servers!**

To me personally the 5 second pause between such requests is a gold standard. The more, the better.

P.S. Sorry, my answer has nothing to do with bs and selenium, but since you've asked for a better solution... :)

EDIT: [The robots.txt file](https://vancouver.craigslist.org/robots.txt) does not directly forbid to call their API, so technically, you are allowed to use it.